# How to match one character word?

Tags: python, regex

How do I match only words of character length one? Or do I have to check the length of the match after I performed the match operation? My filter looks like this:

```
sw = r'\w+,\s+([A-Za-z]){1}
```

So it should match

```
rs =re.match(sw,'Herb, A')
```

But shouldn't match

```
rs =re.match(sw,'Herb, Abc')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `\b\w\b` you will only match one character of type word. So your expression would be

```
sw = r'\w+,\s+\w\b'
```

(since `\w` is preceded by at least one `\s` you don't need the first `\b`)

Verification:

```
>>> sw = r'\w+,\s+\w\b'
>>> print re.match(sw,'Herb, A')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7242058>
>>> print re.match(sw,'Herb, Abc')
None
```

Comment: Now I'm remembering reading about word boundaries...once upon a time...Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
(?<=\s|^)\p{L}(?=[\s,.!?]|$)
```

which will match a single letter that is preceded and followed either by a whitespace character or the end of the string. The lookahead is a little augmented by punctuation marks as well ... this all depends a bit on your input data. You could also do a lookahead on a non-letter, but that begs the question whether “a123” is really a one-letter word. Or “I'm”.

Comment: wuw..I see some lookbehind assertion, some grouping, a class,...but this like over complicating things a bit.

Comment: It won't trip over numbers or underscores, as opposed to the `\w` variant. It will *definitely* match only letters. And it's Unicode-aware, whereas with `\w` that's always a little hit-or-miss, depending on the engine.

Comment: Good that you point that out. Maybe you should update your answer. I was actually going to use `[A-Za-z]`-class which will rule out the numbers and underscores.